Why is Perplexity not reliable for open domain text generation tasks?
In the paper here, it says that perplexity as an automated metric is not reliable for open domain text generation tasks, but it instead uses lm-score, a model based metric to produce perplexity like values. What additional benefits does lm-score give instead of perplexity metric?

The lm-score offers several potential benefits over perplexity by providing a more context-aware semantically focused and adaptable evaluation of language models It aims to address the shortcomings of perplexity, particularly in the context of open domain text generation where maintaining coherence relevance and user satisfaction are crucial By incorporating these additional considerations, the lm-score can provide a more accurate and meaningful assessment of a language model’s performance in generating high-quality text
